# Node js stream file

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a service continuously sending data through a socket.

The data captured after a while looks like this:

```
{base64} \n {base64} \n {base64} ...
```

Where `{base64}` represents an image data.

How can I control the data flow so that I can get one image at a time (in the right order) and do something useful with it.

Right now I just pipe it to a file, but I'm sure there is a better way than to start parsing the file for delimiters and actually implement the back-pressure mechanism myself.

```
var streamRaw = fs.createWriteStream('raw.data');
socket.pipe(streamRaw, {end:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reference [substack's example here](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook/blob/master/example/basics/lines.js):

```
var offset = 0;

socket.on('readable', function () {
    var buf = socket.read();
    if (!buf) return;
    for (; offset < buf.length; offset++) {
        if (buf[offset] === 0x0a) {
            //you have buffered a full image as a base64 string,
            // process it, or emit it as an event
            processImageData(buf.slice(0, offset).toString());
            buf = buf.slice(offset + 1);
            offset = 0;
            socket.unshift(buf);
            return;
        }
    }
    socket.unshift(buf);
});
```

You could also think of you stream as a Transform stream that reads a socket's chunks of data and emits whole sets of base64 image data as they arrive.